How to fill Gap this gap?
I have created a cavity in a cube using Boolean Union Modifer, This has created a gap between the top and bottom layers. I tried filling the gaps by using grid fill and bridge fill. Still, it didn't solve the problem. I want it to be filled and look like the original Cavity without open holes marked in Blue. 
This is how it looks like 

What does it give if you select the edges and right click > LoopTools > Birdge or Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops?

When I select Edges and bridge it doesn't fill the Gap as the top layer has less edges than the bottom

Could you please share your file?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
